# How to make an initial screen to fit every mobile screen or support multiscreens

Tags: android

I am working on an android project. My first screen consists of one imageview and three textviews everything is clearly visible when the mobile positioned vertically if the mobile positioned horizontally then some text views are not visible how to make my app which fits to screen and supports all positions(vertical/horizontal).[image: this is the screen shot]
Thank you.

Comment: First of all..show what you have done regarding this !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `ScrollView` to your layout. As in landscape the screen height is decreased, so lesser area is left to show elements.

[ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) will manage all the things for you. If space available is less than required then Scroll bar will be shown otherwise not.

Comment: thank you for reply without ScrollView How can i make it to fit the screen

Comment: @Varma You need to show us what kind of layout it is (screenshots) and what you are doing right now.

Comment: I added the screenshot

Comment: @Varma Use RelativeLayout, alignParentTop, centerInParent and alignParentBottom

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it will fit on any screen size, consider using `RelativeLayout`, with this you can say where it needs to align on the screen at all times. Of course if it can overflow than using a `Scrollview` is a much safer option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scrollview to fit the screen in length, or you can use PercentRelativeLayout.

How to use a scrollview:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <--yourcodehere-->

        </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Add this to your gradle to use PercentRelativeLayout:

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.0'
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/Tesksten"
    android:id="@+id/btContent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_menu"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_heightPercent="16%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

This is how this button looks now, note that there are more lines to get MY specific layout, remove if needed. Make sure you put Width And height to 0 and then use Percent, i had some problems figuring it out at first to. Goodluck.:

[image: Example]

Or if you want to fully turn off screen rotation, add this to your manifest activity, that you dont want to rotate:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: @Varma Did it fix your problem?

Comment: thank you no method is worked  for me,sorry for late reply